# How to show Marker Bar in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, is there a way to enable/disable the error marker bar next to the text editor?

Mine is currently not showing any marker, although I have compile errors in my code.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Only in Visual Studio 2015 with Roslyn analyze your code in real time such markers can appear. All older VS releases won't show them unless you use a third party tool such as ReSharper.